# Откуда компилятор знает о существование объекта?

Tags: c++

Откуда компилятор знает о существование объекта?

Header.h:

```cpp
void sd() {
    SD sd;
}
```

Header1.h:

```cpp
class SD {};
```

Source.cpp:

```cpp
#include "Header.h"
#include "Header1.h"
```

Так как препроцессор вставляет вместо директивы `include` содержимое файла. Получается что препроцессор передаёт компилятору файл в следующем виде:

```cpp
void sd() {
    SD sd;
}
class SD {}
```

Как я могу тогда использовать объект `SD` если он ещё не опеределён?

Comment: Сделайте [mcve]. Ощущение, что это не будет работать.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat сделал

Comment: Неправда. У вас `;` пропущена - это значит, что на самом деле вы не проверяли код, который нам дали. Прочитайте по ссылке еще раз раздел "воспроизводимость". Но даже если `;` добавить - у меня все равно не работает.

Comment: Вы **точно** проверили код, который нам дали? На каком компиляторе?

Comment: Да, все проверил. Компилятор vs

Comment: [Тут не компилируется](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/b5enMane3). Попробуйте сделать пустой проект, создать там заново эти файлы, и проверить еще раз. Если скомпилируется, выложите на гитхаб и дайте ссылку.

Comment: Перепроверил на чистом проекте, и действительно перестало компилироваться, но как компилятор во время определения объекта знает что это именно тот класс (тк. подсвечивается и никаких ошибок ), который определен ниже? Если изменить название класса, уже будет ошибка что объект например sdf не определен

Comment: Это вы про оригинальный проект спрашиваете? Вангую, что у вас стоит настройка автоматически инклудить какой-то хедер.

Comment: нет, последний код выше

Comment: Я имею в виду, не про новый проект с ошибкой, а про старый проект, где это магическим образом работает.

Comment: про новый проект

Comment: Тогда что значит "как компилятор знает...", если у вас ошибки? Или вы про intellisense?

Comment: про intellisense

Comment: Ну, тут может быть только один ответ. Интеллисенс - глупый.

Comment: intellisense периодически надо сбрасывать, при любом сомнении удаляйте .vs

Answer (score 2):

string Это стандартная библиотека она находится по стандартному пути потому препроцессор знает этот путь и вместо `#include <string>` вставляет в файл код класса. Получается вверху страницы перед `int main(int argc, char* argv[]){}` вместо `#include <string>` появляется код класса string препроцессор просто копирует его туда. Если класс не стандартный, написанный Вами тогда Вы его вставляете таким образом `#include "Путь/к/myclass.h"`. Препроцессор идет по тому пути который Вы указали и копирует оттуда необходимый класс.

Вы описали неправильно взаимодействие вставляемых файлов директивой #include потому Ваш код не будет работать. Чтобы он заработал нужно правильно определить куда необходимо вставлять заголовочные файлы. То есть какой файл от какого зависит. Код должен выглядеть как-то так:

header.h

```
#include "header1.h"


SD sd()
{
    SD sd;
    return sd;
}
```

header1.h

```
#include <iostream>


class SD
{
    public:
        SD()
        {
            std::cout << 
            "A'm class " << 
            typeid(this).name() << 
            std::endl;
        }
};
```

source.cpp

```
#include "header.h"


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    sd();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: почему если я что-то подключаю в .cpp и при этом сам .h файл подключен к .cpp то .h тоже видит все подключения в .cpp

Comment: @Kurr200, потому что после include текст, содержащийся в .h становится частью кода в .cpp

Comment: @avp почему оно работает даже если я подключаю с начало свой .h, а потом `iostream`например ? В `iostream` вроде как хранятся объявление функционала в пространстве имён. Вместо строки `include <iostream>` препроцессор вставляет содержимое файла, получается что содержимое моего файла он быстрее вставит нежели `iostream` и функционал библиотеки  будет объявлен после вставки файла `.h`. Так как тогда `.h` знает об этом?

Comment: @Kurr200, в файле, который отправляется на компиляцию строчки вашего .cpp файла до include будут перед содержимым .h, а строчки после include будут после содержимого .h (в них определения из .h уже будут видны)  Поймите, текст `include "file.h"` просто полностью заменяется на текст из файла `file.h`. Компиляция начинается после всех таких замен

Comment: @avp Исходя из вашего ответа понял только `Поймите, текст include "file.h" просто полностью заменяется на текст из файла file.h. Компиляция начинается после всех таких замен. Компиляция начинается после всех таких замен`

Comment: @avp, возможно вы меня не правильно поняли. Содержимое заголовочных файлов: Header.h: `#pragma once  class SD { };`. Header1.h: `#pragma once void sd() {SD s;}`.  Source.cpp: `#include "Header.h" #include "Header1.h". Компилятору уже передаётся файл в таком в виде: `int sd() { SD sd; }  class SD { }; `   Каким образом функция `sd` использует объект типа `SD`, если к нему ещё не дошло определение?

Comment: @Kurr200, вам уже советовали, могу только повторить. Сделайте минимальный воспроизводимый пример (приведите текст всех ваших файлов в тексте вопроса)